# "'browser_action' is only allowed for extensions" при создании плагина

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

При разработке плагина появляется ошибка:

> 'browser_action' is only allowed for extensions, but this is a legacy packaged app.

Как её исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переделать приложение в расширение. Для этого из манифеста нужно, как минимум, убрать параметр `app`.

Источники:

- [Apps vs extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions) (по-английски)
- [Манифест для приложения](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) (по-английски)
- [Манифест для расширения](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) (по-английски)
- [Похожий вопрос на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431066/how-do-i-change-my-legacy-packaged-app-into-an-extension) (по-английски)